# Specifying a target tab (or window) in a URL

Tags: javascript, html, http, url

I'm still struggling with the issue I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36642584/closing-a-browser-window-after-a-download): I need to send the user a document and the only tool available to me is requesting a URL to be opened in the default browser.

That works fine but if I link to the document directly, the browser (IE, FF, Chrome, Opera and Safari tested) creates a new, empty tab behind.

I would like to find a way to avoid that.

An additional issue is that users can use a very similar functionality to bypass the login screen and go directly to a specific page of the web app. Unfortunately, since all I have to work with is a URL, every time they invoke that function they end up opening a new tab.

So, I thought that one to solve both issue would be to be able to specify the target of the URL (as if the used clicked on a `<a target="mywebapp">` link). Is that possible either through the URL itself or through the web page targeted?

Comment: No, that is not possible. URLs don’t even know that there is such an imaginary construct such as a “window” or a “tab” – they simply got nothing whatsoever to do with those.

Comment: Thanks. And through the HTTP response, maybe ?

Comment: HTTP doesn’t know about windows or tabs either.

Comment: Through javascript served as the answer, then ? Or any other way ?

Comment: What about the "Window-target" HTTP header ?

Comment: I don’t know an HTTP header of that name; but it is possible that some clients might listen to it.